# Stream dynamic BufferedImage to website

Tags: java, html, web-services, html5-canvas

I have a dynamic BufferedImage in java that I'm generating. I want to be able to send the BufferedImage to the web frontend. I want the web frontend to be able to handle refreshing this image at a set interval. Also, I'm going to need keyboard and mouse callbacks. I was researching the HTML5 Canvas but it seems it doesn't really support the kind of thing I'm doing.

Basically, trying to make a game that is generated server-side then the client is sent the BufferedImage of that game at like 5fps or something.

Comment: Can you elaborate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the `Base64.Encoder` class to encode the `BufferedImage` on the server side with Java.  This would convert the image to a base64 `String` that can be shoved into an `img` tag's `src` on the front end.

You would need to save the image to file temporarily, but this should do the job:

```
Base64.Encoder encoder = Base64.getEncoder();
BufferedImage bi = generateYourImage();
ImageIO.write(bi, yourImageExtension, new File(".tmp."+yourImageExtension));
String base64Str = "data:image/"+yourImageExtension+";base64,"+ encoder.encode(Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(".tmp."+yourImageExtension")));
```

Then send `base64Str` to you client and push it into the `src` attr of an `img` tag.

Comment: Will this be able to refresh the image?

Comment: @CharlesDuncan As long as you keep sending the updated `String` to the client.  I'm assuming you're using Angular on the front end?

Comment: I'm using Vaadin for this project at the moment.

Comment: I'm not familiar with that framework, but if it has html interpolation then it should be just fine.  Do you have a way to set attributes of tags with variables in the JS?

Comment: Yeah, I should be able to do that. Does this method have the ability to have Mouse / Keyboard callbacks?

Comment: Not sure exactly what you mean.  Assuming this is a game, this would be the end of your render code for a particular frame.  Your Mouse and Keyboard handlers would be completely separate from this code.

Comment: Imagine the above code is inside of a method called `render()` that returns the `base64Str`.  Essentially this would be the structure of your game loop:

`while(true){  checkUserInput();  String frame = render(); sendFrameToClient(frame);}`